# How to make a Size Object in Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

For the [createThumbnailFromPath](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/all#nativeimagecreatethumbnailfrompathpath-maxsize-macos-windows) method in Electron, I need to pass it a Size object. How do I create a Size object? I tried requiring `electron` and doing `require("electron").remote`, but neither had a Size object. [This page on the Size object](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/structures/size) says nothing on how to make one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a way to denote a particular object interface in the documentation. You can use a plain object with the properties `width` and `height`, i.e. `{ width: 500, height: 500 }`.